# Why my ajax request is not working?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, request

I'm trying to make a request with ajax. When I try it with this webservice:
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

IT WORKS! But when I try it with my service I cannot work with the response.
My function is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
         type: "GET", //REQUEST TYPE
        dataType: "JSONP", //RESPONSE TYPE
        url: "http://mywebservice/method/", // URL OF THE WS
        success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
            var i=0;
            $.each(data,function(i){
              if(data.lenth != i){
                  $('#lista_divisions').append("<option>"+data[i].Name+"</option>"); //fILL THE DDL. FOR EACH ITEM RETURNED ADD DATA[NAME] TO ONE LINE OF THE DDL.
              }  
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and my console in the website doesn't retrieve any error. Can you help me?

**NETWORK TAB:**

[image]

**JSON RESPONSE**

[{"DateAdd":"/Date(1508694576287+0100)/","DateAlter":"/Date(1508694576287+0100)/","DivisionId":1,"Name":"Norte     ","UserAdd":"LoadData","UserAlter":"LoadData","UtlIns":null},{"DateAdd":"/Date(1508694576287+0100)/","DateAlter":"/Date(1508694576287+0100)/","DivisionId":2,"Name":"Sul       ","UserAdd":"LoadData","UserAlter":"LoadData","UtlIns":null}]

Comment: What does your network tab say?

Comment: when you access "http://mywebservice/method/" from your browser what do you see ?

Comment: Well I am guessing you should add an error method to your Ajax call and figure out why it is failing.

Comment: @senojoeht Update. All the 3 lines in network tab are referent to the same request... don't know why I have 3 instead of 1. Something tricky is happening...

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif I see the Json response from the rest ws.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(data.lenth != i)
```

do you mean `length` ?

Your code should loooks like,

```
if(data.length != i)
```

Comment: Yes. You right, I've typed it wrong, but that's not the real problem here... after the change, nothing happened.

Comment: @R.Quintal try to use  map() instead of $.each if dosent slove the problem would you please share with us the json respanse that you got when you access the browser

Comment: Updated. You can check it now @AbdeslemCharif

Comment: I tried your example on jsFiddle i was able to access every element easely using map https://jsfiddle.net/w1zrn4v8/12/

Comment: When I opened jsFiddle and run it i got no response on the console log. I can share the image with you if you want... @AbdeslemCharif

Comment: that wierd , i got a respanse in my console

Answer (score 0):

When you try

```
if(data.lenth != i){
  $('#lista_divisions').append("<option>"+data[i].Name+"</option>"); //fILL THE DDL. FOR EACH ITEM RETURNED ADD DATA[NAME] TO ONE LINE OF THE DDL.
}
```

`data.lenth` surely fails. Are you trying to use `length`?

Comment: Wouldn't it always return true?

Comment: @AndrewBone that's a different problem in OP's logic. Can't see the benefit of having a not-null check against a variable instead of a constant but oh well...

Comment: Yes. You right, I've typed it wrong, but that's not the real problem here... after the change, nothing happened